# Codeigniter database functions and SQL injection

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter database functions like $this->db->insert(); have inbuilt precautions against SQL injection or not?

Answer (score 0):

For CodeIgniter 3 and above versions Yes.
Active records also allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped automatically by the system as per its manual https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

In Codeigniter 2.x.x
No. CodeIgniter does not automatically cleanup against sql injection. You have to do it on you own. One way could be binding the variables

```
$sql="select * from tbl where col=? and col1=?";
$result=$this->db->query($sql,array($col_val,$col1_val))->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Doctrine2 orm framework for database related stuff. This will help you to fix this types of issues.

Please go through below link.

https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/CodeIgniter-with-Doctrine-2?files=1